# How to get memory consumption attributes of a processes in the shell/Terminal as per columns in Activity Monitor?

Tags: terminal, command-line, memory, memory-leak

I have a process that I need to monitor somewhat frequently for growth due to it having a slow leak and the developer being quite unresponsive. (Not important, but since folks ask: This utility is essentially a hardware driver (the new graphical layer in userland that some folks like SiliconMotion use to drive their external display devices) that I can't live without.)

I've found the process grows somewhat slowly over time, but it grows indeterminately and they just won't fix it anytime soon it seems. After a day or so the memory consumption grows into tens of gigabytes.

I need to monitor the memory consumption and kill/restart it when it reaches a certain threshold.

And now, for curiosity's sake in addition to practicality: How can you collect the various memory attributes / columns that one would normally find `Activity Monitor.app` for a process? Example:

[image: columns]

Comment: Can‘t you just run ps with appropriate parameters on that process and get memory use? How is the process named in ps output?

Comment: For some reason the numbers are not really congruent in `ps` vs Activity Monitor... The process is named exactly as in the screenshot: `macOS InstantView` @nohillside.

Comment: There are several questions with answers on the difference between memory reporting done by AM and ps. Does it really matter in your case or can you adjust your trigger logic to the value returned by ps?

Comment: Would using `top` command help at all?

Comment: So here's the thing, regarding `top`: I'm having a devil of a time trying to get it to actually emit some information. Some of the memory columns seem to be "corrupt" or in some fashion not showing proper data. I have tried and tried to use it with `awk` to print the proper column(s), but it's just not working out so far. I'll spend some more time on it and attempt to figure out what is going wrong, but it's been frustrating so far with my hectic schedule.